# Can you run Jython on the JVM that runs on Pulse smart pens?

Tags: jvm, jruby, jython, jvm-languages, livescribe

I'm looking at developing an application that takes advantage of the Pulse smart pen.

I would rather do it in python than java. Its not clear what version of the jvm runs on the pen, as evidence [here in the tech specs](http://www.livescribe.com/media/pdf/Livescribe_Pulse_Specifications.pdf)

Are there limitations on whether or not jython and jruby will run on mobile version of the jvm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Livescribe Java API is based on Java ME; Jython and JRuby require a lot of functionality that isn't in Java ME. Also, I can't imagine the pen would have enough free RAM to run either.

Maybe in a few years.